# How to use multiple mobile Broadband, one for browsing and one for downloading, at the same time

Tags: networking, software-recommendation, mobile-broadband, ip

I have two mobile broadband to connect to the internet. When they connected to the computer both are accessible from the network manager, but only one can be connected at the same time. Currently I use the first one using `nm` one my host OS, for browsing the internet and second one using a guest OS.

How can I use multiple mobile broad band at the same time without using a virtual machine so that I can save the resources used for the virtual machine.

I know this is a difficult task and requires command line play.

There are several possible ways to answer.
 1. Like normal broadband (eth0, eth1) using some IP stuff but mobile broadbands can't be accessible using ppp0,ppp1 (unless they are connected using `nm`)
2. 1'st network for all application and 2'nd for a single application that downloads say `wget`. So 1'st device is connected using `nm` and the other using a special program or something like that (or the downloader th self is capable of that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set up multiple IP addresses (there are several questions on Server Fault for this). Let's say they are `1.2.3.4` and `9.8.7.6`; that is, your computer has the address `1.2.3.4` on one mobile broadband network interface, and `9.8.7.6` on the other. You can then control which network interface each program sends requests on by controlling which local IP address it binds to.

In the Network Manager, use `1.2.3.4` as your default local address. Your browser and other programs will have their requests routed through there.

For your download, specify an option to tell it to bind to the other address. For instance, for `wget` use

```
wget --bind-address=9.8.7.6 http://host.tld/path
```

or for `curl`, I think it's

```
curl --interface interfacename http://host.tld/path
```

where `interfacename` is something like `wlan5:1`. (You might not even need to set up multiple IPs if you're using `curl`, since you specify the network interface directly. I haven't tried this since I only have 1 Internet connection here.)

Comment: OK. Thanks. How can I connect the second Device? I only know `nm`. `ifup` can't be used for ppp by default.

Comment: IP address can be obtained from `ifconfig`. For Eg: `ifconfig ppp0`

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done.

You could create route entries to use one connection for certain IP addresses and another for other IP addresses, but on a website, pages and download are on the same IP address so you couldn't distinguish them using this way.

This support should be implemented within the browser, but it's not, and I suppose they wouldn't even accept patches to do that.

Comment: Why not possible ? See the other answer.